# Listener Return an Arraylist/String

Tags: antlr, antlr4

With an antlr listener, that walks through a parse tree, i have been able to build a Arraylist of  information that i need. But i'm struggling to extract this information outside of the listener.

Example of expectation is:

```
    ...
    ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(Listener, tree);        
    ParseTree tree = myParser.statements();
    //I want to use my Arraylist here
    ...
```

Since the listener does not have a return value, Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

When you define your Listener class (subclass the (`*BaseListener` class), you can have whatever extra data you want on your listener.  In your case, you could create an ArrayList in the constructor of you listener and provide access to it once your `ParseTreeWalker` has walked the tree making Listener callbacks.

Alternatively, you could create your ArrayList in the calling code, and pass it as a parameter to your Listener constructor, to make it available within your Listener code.

BTW, your statements are backwards.  You’ll first need to obtain your `ParseTree` from the parser the you can call the `ParseTreeWalker::walk` method on the tree you got back from the Parser.

Something like:

```
List<YourInfo> yourList = new ArrayList<YourInfo>();
YourListener listener = new YourListener(yourList);
ParseTree tree = myParser.statements();
ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(listener,tree);
// read contents of yourList here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your ArrayList inside your listener.

Code Example

Listener

```java
class MyListener {
    List<Info> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void exitProgram(YourContext ctx) {
        // wrap your info and add it into list here
    }
   
    public List<Info> getMyList() {
        return myList;
    }
}
```

Outside program

```java
MyListener listener = new MyListener();
ParseTree tree = parser.program();
ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
walker.walk(listener, tree);
List<Info> infoList = listener.getMyList();
```